# Consulta para agrupar por fecha SQL

Tags: ms-access

tardes o noches, hace unos dias que estoy intentando realizar una consulta de una **Base de datos de Access 2016**, lo que necesito es que se agrupen los registros dejandome uno solo por dia, pero con el horario de salida del otro registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT Format(Checkinout.CheckTime,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS Fecha, 
       Format(Checkinout.CheckTime,'hh:mm:ss') AS Hora,           
FROM Checkinout;
```

Hay alguna manera de realiza esto.

Desde ya muchisimas gracias por la ayuda.

Un abrazo grande

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en sql server o access? por favor, usa el boton [edit] y aclara eso...

Comment: Hola, si no revise bien el texto del mensaje antes de enviarlo y se corto el saludo inicial, igual se corta no entiendo por que.

Comment: No se corta.. la plataforma lo elimina automaticamente pues no es necesario en esta pagina tanta formalidad... mira [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3149/324)

Comment: para cada fecha, queres el max y el min de esa fecha?

Comment: Gracias por el dato con respecto al saludo, en cuanto a la fecha no entiendo a qué te referis, lo que necesitaría es que en lugar de tener 2 filas con la misma fecha, tener 1 sola pero con los 2 horarios, cómo está en la imagen. Gracias por tu atención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tenes que agrupar por fecha, y por cada registro, solo quedarte con el maximo y el minimo de la otra columna...

```
SELECT Format(Checkinout.CheckTime,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS Fecha, 
       min(Format(Checkinout.CheckTime,'hh:mm:ss')) AS Hora, 
       max(Format(Checkinout.CheckTime,'hh:mm:ss')) AS HoraS 
FROM Checkinout
group by Format(Checkinout.CheckTime,'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me sirvio muchisimo. Un saludo